# How to make Windows Phone 8 Emulator work with Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I was using Windows 8 Pro (64 bit) with VS 2012 Update 3 to develop Windows 8 Phone Application with the Emulator and Device Debugging features.

After I installed Windows 8.1 Pro, I am unable to use the Emulator anymore.
The Compatibility Error window pops up and takes me to a help page. If I continue then I get one error code 0x80131500

The KB Article says this problem affects Windows 8.1 Preview and the solution is to install VS2012 Update 3 which I already have.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem the other day. I solved it by installing Visual Studio 2012 [update 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872520/en)